# Basic formula manipulation related with Legendre symbol

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers

> Using the fact that $i$ = cos$\frac \pi2$ + $i$sin$\frac \pi2$, show that
>   $$\frac{(1+i^p)i^{-p/2}}{(1+i)i^{-1/2}} = \frac{cos\frac {p\pi}4}{cos\frac \pi4}$$

I found this problem when studying about Legendre symbol so I tag it as number theory.

Comment: Do you know anything more about the connection to the Legendre symbol here? It looks like a fairly straightforward exercise in complex analysis: use $\cos\theta = \frac{e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta}}{2}$ and $i = e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}$.

Comment: But. These are ordinary fractions here and not Legendre symbols, right?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$(1+i^{2k})i^{-k}=i^k+i^{-k}=2\cos\frac{k\pi}{2}$$

as $i^k= \cos\frac{k\pi}{2}+i\sin\frac{k\pi}{2}$ and $i^{-k}=?$

Comment: you mean cos$\frac {k\pi}2$ ... right?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee The OP is right, you need $\frac{k\pi}{2}$ instead of $k$ in your trigonometric functions here.

Comment: @SamStreeter, SOrry I misread  it

Comment: @KiYoonEum, Your are correct